# ejb TimerService.getAllTimers() target beans?

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-7

I can get all timers in a EJB module using getAllTimers() on TimerService. These timers run on different EJB's. Is there a way to know on which bean a Timer runs?
Or is the only way explicitly setting this in the Timer info at creation time?

Comment: Setting info on the timer on creation will solve this issue. Is there a reason why you would like to avoid this solution?

Comment: Just to see if there's a generic way to retrieve Timer info, without having to modify creation of all Timers. With getTimers() this info is implicit but scoped to a single bean. So I was hoping to get the same info, out of the box, with a broader scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get additional info about each timer. But you need to cast timers to classes from container implementation.

Comment: OK, I interpret this answer as there is no portable and automatic way to get info on the bean on which the timer runs. Thanks.